# R: read.table with string NA

Tags: r, string, na

Here's my data:

```
KEY ID      name
1   sadsa   ffsadsa
2   vdffsfs fsadfgg
3   3e4dsa  NA
4   vs12ffs ghg
```

When I load my data file in R, R treats NA as missing values. However, the NA is actual response in my data (I want R to treat it as string). How can I make the "NA" as string without treating it as missing value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using the `na.strings` option in `read.table`:

```
text <- "KEY  ID  name
1   sadsa   ffsadsa
2   vdffsfs fsadfgg
3   3e4dsa  NA
4   vs12ffs ghg"

df <- read.table(text = text,
                header = TRUE,
                na.strings = "",
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$name
[1] "ffsadsa" "fsadfgg" "NA"      "ghg"
```